# Ubuntu: Edit environment variables via command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, environment-variables

How can you edit the environment variables via command line in ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

You can set environment variables from the command line, but the new values will apply only to that terminal session and any processes launched from it. Environment variables are handled differently in Unix than they are in Windows. When a Unix process is created, it inherits an environment from its parent process that includes environment variables.  Changes to a process's environment affect that process and its children, but not any other processes.

With that caveat, you can set an environment variable in a Bourne-like shell such as bash like this:

```
export MYVAR=myvalue
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/environment`. When you log out and log back in, the new values will be present.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify/set environment variable(s) **for your current shell session**, which will last until you close/exit it, then

```
export MYVAR=value
```

If you want to modify/set environment variable(s) to be present **every time you run your shell**, then you should modify your shell's config file to include the above line.

To find out what shell you're running, type:

```
# echo $SHELL
```

Then edit the appropriate configuration file:

- For `sh` you would modify `~/.profile`
- For `bash` you would modify `~/.bashrc`
- For `zsh` you would modify `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv`

Where the `~` character in each case represents the path to your home directory. If editing on the command line, you can just use it directly, e.g. to open the file in the `vim` editor:

```
# vim ~/.profile
```

If you're using a GUI-based editor you should just navigate to your home directory to find the appropriate config file.

Answer (score 0):

To set TEST to XYZ, use this format:

TEST=XYZ; export TEST

Answer (score 0):

I also found it useful to install nano and edit the text of the environment file which in my case was found in the `/etc` folder.

```
sudo apt-get install nano
sudo nano filename
```

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but this answer is not very useful or clear. Installing nano isn't really necessary to fix the problem, nor do you actually ever list the file you're using nano to edit. It looks like several other people posted solutions that are more thorough, you should consider accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the `@drfrogsplat` answer.

Once you have made the change in either `~./profile` or `~./bashrc`. It's necessary to use the following command to reflect the changes.

`$ source ~./bashrc`